# Rewrite one directory to another .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to automatically redirect http requests to `news/images` to `../images`.

Is that possible with .htaccess?

Thing is: request to `www.site.tld/news/images ...` should go to `www.site.tld/images ...`

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
...
...
RewriteRule (.*)news/images(.*) ../images [R=301,L]
```

not working.

I have ensured that apache have `mod_rewrite.c` enabled.

Comment: There are about 53974783027 answers to this alone here on StackOverflow. None of those helped you? _Why not_? And why should the 53974783028th suddenly help? What should be different with the one you ask here? Please read through a few of the "Related" entries shown on the right side. I am sure you will find your question answered there.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect all requests for `/news/images/` to `/images/`, capture the part after `images` and use it in the `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^news/images(.*)$ /images$1 [R,L]
```

---

When it works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301`. Never test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^www\.site\.tld/news/images$ /www.site.tld/images?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

or you can also use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.tld/news/images$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.tld/images/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But as @arkascha said, please do some research first, there are MANY answers to this sort of problem! :) Either way, I hope this helps.

Comment: `HTTP_HOST` is the hostname only, without path info. And the `RewriteRule` pattern is only path info, without hostname. See [Apache Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks @OlafDietsche, I will take a look! :)